# rename url "localhost/wp-admin" for dashboard in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, vps

I'm trying to change the address:

```
"http://localhost/wp-admin"
```

to:

```
"http://localhost/tutor"
```

and try different plugins and they work but the problem is that when a user enters:

```
"http://localhost/tutor"
```

wp-admin appears again

```
"http://localhost/tutor/wp-admin"
```

or

```
"http//localhost/wp-admin"
```

how can I rename wp-admin?.
I need to make that change for security reasons

Comment: Try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/protect-wp-admin/

Comment: already try with that plugin and "wp-admin" still appears

Comment: Yes, check them before asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, this plugin changes the login URL(wp-admin.php) and the administrator URL(wp-admin)

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hide-security-enhancer/

Comment: this plugin is the only one that works - the premium one does work for nginx too

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is slightly a big one.

Firstly there are a few plugins, search for them. I use `wp-better-security` or something like that. It used to be called `ithemes-security`.

Secondly, if you wish to do it yourself:

Caveat emptor, do at own risk

1. BACKUP EVERYTHING, FILES AND DB
2. In `wp-config.php` you'll need to redefine the wp-content dir and url globals.
3. Rename your folder
4. Venerate the Machine Spirit
5. Refresh your page.

Comment: I already tried that and it did not work either

Comment: Try iThemes Security https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/. You may have to manually rename the folder after you press the "rename folder" button.

Comment: thanks, but it did not work either, Yes, it was changed to: "http://localhost/tutor" but wp-admin appears again: "http://localhost/tutor/wp-admin"

Comment: I only just read that you want to change the `admin` folder. I don't think it's possible. If you're worried about people logging in, the plugin I recommended will allow you to obsure it so you'll need to go to site.com/tutor to login and site.com/wp-login will 404.

Comment: Exactly !!, when a client has already logged in to his control panel, he can see the URL "localhost / wp-admin" and I need to change the url to "localhost / tutor", I do not want to reveal to the client that he is using wordpress

Comment: might be more a apache/nginx thing. This (admittedly old) post on WPSE states it's impossible. Maybe move it to there too. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106/can-i-rename-the-wp-admin-folder

Comment: Well, thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

To hide admin from url when you login use below plugin it will easily add slug which you want.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/

Comment: thanks, but I need to change the control panel url "localhost/wp-admin" to "localhost/tutor" not login url

Comment: You can take the name tutor replace login. On setting panel. What you want